# Improving Scratch player performance

Tags: graphics, flash

I have written a Scratch version of "Conway's Game of Life" as an illustrative tool - it needs some more refinement but the computational code is all there: see http://scratch.mit.edu/projects/adrianmcmenamin/3163145

Running it on the Scratch website using the Flash player, it races along but leaves a nasty echo of each dead cell, while using the Java player it is much cleaner but very slow.

My question is - how can I ensure that the shapes I draw (whether the current Xs or any other shape) are cleanly written over in the Flash player. Unfortunately Scratch isn't really designed in such a way that I can post code segments here, but the code essentially draws a cross in red if a cell is 'living' and in white if it has died - the code to locate the position of either cross is the same.

**Update**: I think I could reframe this question more simply by asking "is there a way to force Scratch to output raster graphics in a truly consistent manner eg., thickness of line, etc?"